# Utilisation du subjonctif après "dont"

Tags: subjonctif, pronoms-relatifs

Dans la phrase suivante, le verbe "rendre" est conjugué au subjonctif. Qu'est-ce qui justifie cet emploi, sachant que "dont" ne fait pas partie des locutions derrière lesquelles on emploi le subjonctif ? (http://grammaire.reverso.net/1_1_20_Le_subjonctif.shtml)

> Existe-t-il un ensemble de fichiers informatiques dont la perte (ainsi
>   que les sauvegardes dématérialisées) **rende** impossible la présentation
>   d’un document légalement attendu?

Cette phrase est extraite d'un questionnaire

Comment: Dont n'est pas une locution, c'est un pronom relatif et la page à laquelle tu renvoie parle aussi des propositions relatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dont** introduit une **proposition relative** et il est tout à fait possible de mettre le subjonctif dans des propositions relatives.

La phrase de l'exemple est formée d'une principale qui est une question (*Existe-t-il un ensemble de fichiers informatiques*) et la relative exprime une perte hypothétique (*dont la perte rende impossible la présentation d’un document légalement attendu*) ?
L'emploi du subjonctif permet de laisser un doute sur l'existence d'un tel ensemble de fichiers. L'emploi de l'indicatif, qui serait aussi possible, indique qu'on est sûr de l'existence d'un tel ensemble de fichiers.

Grevisse décrit ainsi ce cas d'emploi du subjonctif dans la proposition relative (les exemples sont de moi) :

- « Quand la relative restreint une proposition principale négative (de forme ou de sens), dubitative, interrogative ou conditionnelle. »

  > Y a-t-il quelqu'un dans la salle qui sache faire marcher cet ordinateur ?
  >
  > Je ne connais personne à qui je puisse faire confiance.
  >
  > Si je trouve un tableau qui me plaise je l’achèterai.

Il donne d'autres cas d'emplois du subjonctif dans la proposition relative :

- « Quand on marque un but à atteindre, une intention » :

  > Je tiens à faire un choix dont je puisse être fier plus tard.
- Quand l'antécédent contient un superlatif ou une expression de
  valeur analogue formée au moyen d'un des adjectifs *seul, premier,
  dernier, unique, suprême*.

  > Paris est la plus belle ville que je connaisse.