# How can I say "it was the first thing that came to mind"?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique

I was wondering how do I specifically say "it was the first thing that came to mind" as in this instance I have to describe an image (about badminton) but am wary of the different meanings and translations of 'something'.

Comment: What are you different attempts at saying this into French?

Answer (score 3):

> C'**est** la première chose qui me **soit** venue à l'esprit.

Strictly speaking, I believe that the presence of the phrase « la première » requires the use of the past subjunctive « soit venue » instead of « est venue ». Then again, both might work.

Also, I would personally use the present tense « est » instead of « était », since the past tense is used in the part « soit venue ». I’d rather avoid using the past tense twice.

Comment: I don't see why you would use 'soit' instead of 'est'... I'm pretty sure only 'est' works. Well, I can't blame you, since even for natives it's a common mistake. That aside, I agree with your answer.

Comment: @NathanCoustenoble Hi. As I understand it, when you have a phrase such as "le premier / le seul", you need to use the subjunctive form in the subordinate clause (that is, strictly speaking). This is what I heard from a native French speaker working as an interpreter in my office. Am I wrong here? Merci.

Comment: I would say both are correct.

Comment: @LUNA Need would not be the word I'd use but it is the most usual as I wrote there answering a very similar question : http://french.stackexchange.com/a/21453/358.

Comment: @Laure Oh, I see. How would you express this sentence yourself, Laure? Merci.

Comment: Sorry if I made a mistake. However, I'm 95% sure 'est' also works because the event happened, and in this case, one should generally use indicative (don't know how to say 'indicatif' in english) instead of subjontive (again...). Well, correct me if I'm wrong, I may have forgotten an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the debatable question of which tense is to be used, I'm a bit surprised to see all answers propose this kind of translation:

> C'[est|était] la première chose qui **me** [soit|est|était] venue à l'esprit.

Maybe (as a French native speaker) I have a bad comprehension of the implicit sense the original sentence may bring in English, but the first translation that *came into **my** mind* (oh! What a coincidence) is rather:

> C'[est|était] la première chose qui [vienne|vient|venait] à l'esprit.

In other words the original sentence might talk about what comes to the mind of anybody, rather than to the speaker itself.

Comment: Hi. Actually, this set expression "come/spring to mind" means that a thought or an idea occurs to a **specific** person (and in this case, to the speaker himself). So it would be the same as to say "It was the first thing that came to (**my**) mind", even though this is not grammatical.

Comment: @LUNA Thanks for this clarification. But conversely it now makes me wonder how, in English, we can express something like "C'est la première chose qui vient à l'esprit" (implied "de [quiconque|chacun|tout le monde|tout un chacun|...]"), without the risk of confusing with "à mon esprit"?

Comment: Hi. In that case, I would use "**come into** their minds" or "**occur to** them", among other things.

Comment: @LUNA Oh! So, while in French no precision means "[any|every]body" and it needs "me" to regard only the speaker, conversely English means "me" by default and needs "[their|them]" to regard everybody. Correct?

Comment: Hi. The expression "come/spring to mind" is a special instance where a possessive pronoun "my" is not required. On the other hand, when you use "come into" or "occur to", you need to say "come into my mind" or "occur to me". The "my/me" here cannot be omitted.

Comment: I think, in English at least, in the present tense, the general (non-individual-specific) notion that you describe in your good answer (+1, yesterday) is present in "[Generally,] It's the first thing that COMES to mind" even if "Generally" is omitted. However, this notion of "Generally" (whether spoken or omitted as understood) is harder to include/imagine when using the past tense to speak of a thing that HAS ALREADY COME to a specific mind & in that case I think it would be idiomatic to include the appropriate possessive pronoun:"It's the first thing that CAME to my/her/etc mind."

Comment: @LUNA Sorry, I realize I didn’t pay sufficient attention to your previous comment: I focused on the presence/absence of the possessive, while I now understand that the real difference stays in the couple verb+conjunction. This is pretty confusing for a French speaker. Anyway, I also (lately) realize I’m polluting the FrenchLanguage area with what should rather go to the EnglishLanguageLearners one! So I stop doing that. Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: @PapaPoule As absolutely not fluent with English, I must confess that there're cases where I have trouble to _deeply_ understand some precise explanations. Especially here I'm quite embarrassed: after thought I'd finally understood the last LUNA's comment, reading the yours (in its first part) now I feel that it states the opposite! More over, reading the second part suggests me to talk about the past tense case. But I don't want to continue: as explained in my comment to LUNA, it's not the right place. I think I'll post a question in EnglishLanguageLearners, trying to clearly explain all that

Answer (score 2):

"C'était la première chose qui m'est venue en tête".  Or you could also say it like "C'était la première chose qui m'est venue à l'esprit".

So 'Something' means 'quelque chose' in French.  'Thing' means 'chose' in French as well.  In French just like in English, you would not want to use 'thing' to describe a specific object or action.

Comment: venu**e**, no ?

Comment: Oops, that's right! My bad.  I forgot that 'chose' in feminine and venu does need an 'e'.

Comment: @12Lapointep You can edit posts you know